# Find three largest contour(achieve two now)

Tags: c, linux, opencv, area, contour

friends, I am coding using opencv. I want to find three largest contour in picture/video, I have write code that can find two largest contour, I have difficulty in finding third largest, so I need your suggestions,Merry Christmas!
Here is my core code, how to change.

```
CvSeq *cont = 0
cvFindContours( tempImg, storage, &cont, sizeof(CvContour), 
CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0) ); 

CvSeq *contmax = 0;
CvSeq *contmax2 = contmax;

for(;cont;cont = cont->h_next) //get the two max area, and mark
{
    area = fabs(cvContourArea( cont, CV_WHOLE_SEQ )); 
    printf("area == %lf\n", area);
    if(area > maxArea)
    {
        contmax2 = contmax;
        max2Area = maxArea;
        contmax = cont;
        maxArea = area;
    }
    else if(area > max2Area && area < maxArea)
    {
        contmax2 = cont;
        max2Area = area;
    }

}
CvRect aRect = cvBoundingRect( contmax, 0 );
CvRect bRect = cvBoundingRect( contmax2, 0 );
```

Comment: Can you give us some sample input and output and a way to compile and execute your program ourselves?

Comment: Oh, that's a very long code, I am writing program for robot vision. I compile it using gcc in Linux. you can take tempImg as input.

Comment: It would be very helpful for us to be able to compile something so we can debug it.

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach? Why can't you use it for 3 contours instead of 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?:

```
#define N 3

double maxArea[N] = {0};
CvSeq *countours[N], *tmp_cont;
double tmp_area;

for(;cont;cont = cont->h_next)
{
    area = fabs(cvContourArea(cont, CV_WHOLE_SEQ));
    printf("area == %lf\n", area);

    for(int i = N-1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if(area > maxArea[i])
        {
            maxArea[i] = area;
            countours[i] = cont;
            for(int j = (i-1); j >= 0; --j)
            {
                if(maxArea[j] < maxArea[j+1])
                {
                    tmp_area = maxArea[j+1];
                    tmp_cont = contours[j+1];
                    maxArea[j+1] = maxArea[j];
                    contours[j+1] = contours[j];
                    maxArea[j] = tmp_area;
                    contours[j] = tmp_cont;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi,Faust, the number of all contours is about 20, now I need to find three largest contours. According to your code, contours[0],contours[1] and contours[2] are three largest contours, right?

Comment: Good strategy! I go to try it now, Thx!

Comment: Yes, it can work!But I printf maxArea[0] maxArea[1] maxArea[2], maxArea[0] is a very big number, maxArea[1] and [2] are 0, what's wrong? double?

Comment: Oh, solved it. I didn't declare area and maxArea as same variables, both int or double. Thx

Comment: Hi, Faust. I find a new problem, the program skip the second largest area.For example, actual areas are 1,6,2,5,4,9,3 but it will display 9,5,4 as three largest areas, where is 6?

Comment: OMG,the largest area is correct, but the second and third may be wrong, sometimes all correct. what happened

Comment: Ops..I forgot to make the comparisons in order. I'll fix as soon as possible. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, this one can work. It can show three largest, but contours[2] is the largest, contours[1]is the second, contours[0] is the third....how to change?  maxArea[j] < maxArea[j-1] change to > ?

Comment: Because I hope contours[0] is the larggest. sorry to distub you in silent night, Merry Christmas!

Comment: Edited. However don't worry, it is not silent night here :). Merry Christmas!

Comment: I tried new code, display "segmentation fault", seems that something not considered.  your last code can run fluently, I tried just now.

Comment: the number of contours may be from 0 to 50, depend on different situation.

Comment: It will be better if you give me the complete code to debug. My built-in gdb have some limitations :P

Comment: No problem, because I can not post my complete code here, so May I email code to you? But I think you can not compile it, I am using OpenCV in Linux. you can take a look.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0kgnD6AdYrdR09TQmdZMmp0ZkU/edit?usp=sharing    here is the link, I save it in google drive

Comment: after it printf the third area in first loop, then the program stuck.

Comment: The code that you have posted is not complete so I can't compile and test it. But I can see that you changed many variable names, sometimes inconsistently, for example "j" in the inner for.

Comment: I think you are right, I found my fault,there are several inconsistent, I should practice more and debug for myself. I really appreciate you. I should go to sleep, Singapore time is 1.30 am now.Thanks again.

Comment: Now program can run, your code is correct. I still have a long way to go. Good night!